# Jersey get method which will be invoked

Tags: java, jersey

I'm trying to implement `ContainerRequestFilter` which would check if method which should be invoked is annotated with @Authorize and if it is, invoke method which will check if user is authorized and based on return value either return `not Authorized` or proceed with request.

Now I wonder is there an easy way to get info on which method will be invoked if I proceed with the request?

Comment: Are you using spring framework? You can check [AspectJ](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/) also

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory` wich is shipped with jersey to get an idea of how that is supposed to work. The factory implements `ResourceFilterFactory` and its sole method to implement is:

```
 List<ResourceFilter> create(AbstractMethod am);
```

This way you can get hold of the method you were called for. You can pass the abstract method to your filter or construct the right filter beforehand.